# Mysql export data as JSON from command line not working

Tags: mysql

I am using below command to download select query records into the json file:

```
mysql -h <host> -u <username> <DatabaseName> -p -e  "select JSON_OBJECT("test", id,"test1", subject_name, "test2", subject_desc) from test;" > test_data.json
```

but not working from command line, working from tool

Comment: SO what is the input? What does that code Output? Or are there error message s??

Comment: @RiggsFolly getting this error "ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'"

Comment: Don't use double quotes for string literals, use single quotes.

Comment: @stickybit Ignore last silly message :) Not firing on all cylinders this morning :)

Comment: @stickybit even with single quote getting wrong response, because subject_desc has json data stored

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the database name with `-p <name_database>` on which execute the query

Answer (score 0):

you are using double quotes around your key names, but you are inside a double quoted literal already. Change the wrapper on your keys to single quotes

```
mysql -h <host> -p -e  "select JSON_OBJECT('test', id,'test1', subject_name, 'test2', subject_desc) from test;" > test_data.json
```

You may also need to specify a database name

```
mysql -h <host> -p DatabaseName -e  "select JSON_OBJECT('test', id,'test1', subject_name, 'test2', subject_desc) from test;" > test_data.json
```

Comment: There is no error in database, I am getting field error which is not working